# Как отследить событие position: sticky

Tags: javascript

```js
$('.header h1').Stickyfill();
```

```css
.header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 26px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  background-color: #333;
}

.content span {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wilddeer/stickyfill/master/dist/stickyfill.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <h1>Sticky block</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
  <span>Content text Content text Content text</span>
</div>
```

Нужно поменять css блока с `position: sticky`.

Как "отловить" событие, когда блок начинает скролиться вниз?

P.s. для кроссбраузерности использую библиотеку stickyfill.js, автора - https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill

Копался в ней, но в виду слабого знания js, не получилось найти конкретное событие.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/pJRRKW

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, что должен был показать пример по ссылке?

Comment: @Grundy То для чего библиотека `Stickyfill`․

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, Но ведь автор вопроса не спрашивал для чего эта библиотека

Comment: @Grundy Доп информация, поскольку у автора и подключение библиотеки здесь не нормально было.

Comment: А вот так не пойдёт? - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky

Answer (score 0):

Такого события не существует. Можно отловить прокрутку страницы и по позиции понять, когда блок прилипает.

Comment: А если этот блок находится то ниже, то выше, в зависимости от страницы?

Comment: Я понимаю, что можно подключить на каждой странице свой js файл, в котором отследить скролл на n-ое кол-во пикселей и применить стили к  нужному мне блоку. Но разве нет какого-то более изящного решения?

Comment: @Kellok вероятно, библиотека http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/ сможет тебе помочь. Там есть event `sticky_kit:stick`